# min3D not showing Blender 2.63 Texxture

Tags: android, android-animation

I created a Blender 3D model, exported the Blender project as .obj format. While exporting I made sure that I selected include Normals, Keep vertex order. This project contains a sphere which was UV unwrapped with a JPG file.

I got two files, 1) .obj file and .mtl file. I changed them to _mtl and _obj files.

Please find the content of mtl file below

```
     # Blender MTL File: 'Earth.blend'
     # Material Count: 1
     newmtl earth_test.jpg
     Ns 96.078431
     Ka 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
     Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
     Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
     Ni 1.000000
     d 1.000000
     illum 2
     map_Kd test.jpg
```

I made sure that there are no spaces in _mtl files. test.jpg file is present in res/drawable folder. I also kept earth_test.jpg file in res/drawable folder.

I loaded the obj file using the following code.

```
scene.lights().add(new Light());

IParser parser = Parser.createParser(Parser.Type.OBJ,
        getResources(), "com.geeks.begining:raw/earth_obj", true);
parser.parse();

objModel = parser.getParsedObject();

objModel.scale().x = objModel.scale().y = objModel.scale().z = .8f;
scene.addChild(objModel);
```

Still when the app is loaded texture is missing. Only a sphere is displayed. It looked like the image in Blender in Solid view.

Am I still missing something? Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what is the problem. My Texture image was a bit lesser in size I changed the size and now it worked :)

Comment: I know it is an old thread, but, could you explain what you mean by size? Is it the bitmap size, or the weight of the file (which is due to compression)